# Infinitely many dwarves wearing hats of 2 colours

Tags: mathematics, hat-guessing

I have heard of the puzzle with 100 or 10 dwarves wearing a hat of a color, either red or blue, and standing in a straight line, and having to guess the color of their own hat - it's quite easy.

The solution to save all dwarves or all dwarves minus the first one is fairly simple and relies on the fact that the number of dwarves is finite. 
So what would happen if you had an **infinite number of dwarves** standing in a straight line?

Every dwarf wears a hat of color either red or blue and sees the color of the hats of all the dwarves standing in front of him. There is explicitly a first dwarf, who has to start guessing the color of his hat and then the guessing proceeds with the next one in the line.

If a dwarf guessed correctly, it is freed; if he guessed wrong, it is fried. Every dwarf can hear the voice of all other dwarves without a problem. Everybody is only allowed to speak out either the color red or blue, but no further information.

Is there a possibility for all dwarves to be freed? Well, probably no.

But is it at least possible that only finitely many of them are killed?

EDIT: This is a mathematical puzzle. No loopholes.

Comment: I think you should specify that the dwafs are facing the "infinite" direction. More specifically, that the dwarfs can be labeled by natural numbers, where each dwarf sees the dwarfs greater than it.

Comment: Are they allowed to discuss any kind of strategy before they go into this situation?

Comment: Is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoners_and_hats_puzzle#Countably_Infinite_Hat_Problem_with_Hearing) what you are searching for?

Comment: @dmg I don't understand that at all. There is an infinite number of possible sequences of hats a dwarf can see in front of him, so making a label for each sequence would be impossible. Especially if the only labels you can offer are "red" and "blue". I.e, just because the guy behind me says blue can't possibly determine whether my hat is red or blue, no matter what I see in front of me. Is there a way I can see examples of this in action?

Comment: @EFrog have a look at [my answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/7822/5610). It can be hard to wrap your head around it, but so are infinite dwarves.

Comment: I'm a little lost. What happens if every dwarf is wearing the same color hat? Or the colors are in a ratio of 7:3? Do there need to be an even number of blue and red hats?

Comment: Can I just check whether the other dwarfs, or at least the one in front of a dwarf, can tell whether the latest nominee is freed or fried?

Comment: Would you please pick a consistent terminology for directions?  First you say "in front of", then you say "first" and then "next in line".  It's all unnecessarily confusing to someone who doesn't already know what you're talking about.   Also the first sentence is quite a muddle to someone who is not already familiar with the problem, and you quickly lead into a spoiler for it as well (well, it *might* be a spoiler, as soon as someone figures out what you mean by the first problem).  How about trying to restructure the whole thing in a clear non-spoiler way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This puzzle has been discussed on the Mathematics Stack Exchange as in this question: [Prisoners Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032928/prisoners-problem).

The solution given there (by [Asaf Karagila](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/622/asaf-karagila)):

> Encode the colors into $0$
>   and $1$, and define the equivalence relation on $2^\Bbb N$, $\langle x_i\rangle\sim\langle y_i\rangle$ if and only if there is some $k$
>   such that for all $n\geq k$, $x_n=y_n$. Using the axiom of choice the
>   prisoners pick a representative from each equivalence class.
>
> In his turn, the $n$-th prisoner looks for the representative class
>   fitting the string of hats he sees ahead, assuming that all hats up to
>   him are blue. Since all the prisoners follow the same representative
>   to guess their own color, it is guaranteed that after finitely many
>   deaths, the representative and the fashionable selection of hats by
>   the warden will agree, and everyone else will survive.

Note that since the Axiom of Choice is non-constructive, so is this solution and hence may not be practically useful for the dwarves in the question. There seems to be a fair bit of discussion on whether the Axiom of Choice is required. Well it was shown by Hardin and Taylor [Hardin, Christopher S.; Taylor, Alan D.
An introduction to infinite hat problems.
*Math. Intelligencer* **30** (2008), no. 4, 20–25] that there being **no** winning strategy is consistent with ZF (plus other axioms which don't imply the Axiom of Choice). So in that sense the Axiom of Choice is necessary for a winning strategy.

Answer (score 7):

The solution is the following:

We define the notion of a class of infinite sequence of hats. All sequences in this class differ from each other by only a **finite** number of elements. There are an **infinite** number of classes, each containing a **infinite** number of elements.

Why? As differences between classes are of **infinite length**, there is an **infinite number** of possible distances, which means there is an **infinite number** of classes.

For each such class we select a "representative" which is a single element of the class (a single infinite sequence of hats). <s>So suppose we have the class "infinitely alternating red and blue, with a finite number of non-alternating hats in the first 20 elements". We can set the representative to be:</s>

**EDIT:** Apparently, after digging a bit, a good way to define the classes is:

**Two sequences are equivalent if they are identical after a finite number of items**

**Choice of a representative can be easily defined as choosing the sequence where the differences appear at the beginning of the sequence and are lexicographically smaller.**

For example, the sequence

```
rbrbrbrbrbrb...
```

And, the sequence:

```
r[r]rb[br]rbrbrb... ([] denotes mismatches)
```

is a member of that class. Each dwarf can see the infinite sequence of hats in front of it and can recognize the class. The dwarves can see the mismatches in front of them, but do not know if their own hat is not a mismatch.

But, the difference is finite, and a modification of the standard rules for guessing a finite sequence can be applied. The first dwarf says "red" if there is an odd number of hats that are different in the "sequence", compared to the "representative" (or "blue" if the mismatches are even). From there on, each dwarf has sufficient info to tell the colour of their hat.

Note that, the number of classes is **infinite**, however, since we are talking about infinite dwarves, I assume this is acceptable.

Finally, since the first dwarf "guesses", the first dwarf has a 50% chance of survival, all other dwarves survive.

Oh, and because of the infinite number of classes, this can be directly applied to the problem with an **infinite number of colours**.

**Summary for the naysayers**

- **Two sequences are equivalent if they are identical after a finite number of items.**
- **Choice of a representative can be easily defined as choosing the sequence where the differences appear at the beginning of the sequence and are lexicographically smaller.**
- **As the sequence is infinite, and differences are finite, there exists an infinite subsequence, that can uniquely define the class of the sequence.**

Comment: There is discussion at: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20187/discussion-on-answer-by-dmg-infinite-dwarfs-wearing-infinite-hats-of-2-colours

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I tried to move the comments to chat, purged all the comments, and then realized I couldn't undelete my comment with the chatroom link on mobile. My bad; thanks for finding it.

Comment: I think you should mention that the axiom of choice is being used to pick the representative elements. You can't choose the lexicographically smallest element of the class, as there may be no minimum like for rrrrrr... . There is no constructive algorithm to find representatives.

Comment: How do we choose the class? It is because each dwarf is preceded by a finite number of dwarfs, and therefore can always see the class after him?

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, exactly.

Comment: @xnor : but then, for a dwarf to recognize the class, he must only look at hats that every dwarfs can see, doesn't he?

Comment: @njzk2 That's right. It's not a finite algorithm, if that's your concern. It's a function of infinitely many bits.

Comment: While this is an interesting theory, is it even possible to recognize the class?  The number of classes is uncountably infinite, the same as the real numbers.  I find it hard to believe that this could work unless the sequence is repeating (i.e. rational, and thus, countable).

Comment: @Trenin What do you mean? We can recognize PI, can't we?

Comment: @dmg If you saw the binary expansion of sqrt(PI-e), would you be able to recognize it?

Comment: @dmg You can probably recognize a finite number of classes, and I will concede that the dwarves can recognize a countably infinite number of classes, but there are uncountably infinity number of classes, and I don't see how they could do that.

Comment: @Trenin And I don't see how there are infinite dwarves, and infinite hats and so on... Arguing over whether imaginary dwarves can memorize uncountably infinite classes is quite ridiculous.

Comment: @Trenin: The question is clearly physically impossible. Even if it were possible for infinitely many dwarfs to exist (which it is not), it's not possible for light from an infinite row of dwarfs to reach the first dwarf in finite time, so he can't ever "see all the hats" as stated. The only meaningful way to respond to the problem is to say something interesting about (physically impossible) operations on infinite data, and about what infinite data it is you're operating on, and what operations you're doing. Drawing a line and saying, "too infinite for me" just rules out some of the interest.

Comment: @SteveJessop I'm guessing that infinite dwarves, might get squashed into a black hole or something? Possibly devour the universe? Or stop time? Guess that is a solution as well :)

Comment: @dmg: asphyxiate when the straight line of dwarfs extends beyond the atmosphere ;-) What it means for the universe itself to be infinite can go on physics.stackexchange. No doubt an ultra-finitist mathematician would respond to the question by saying, "sorry, how many dwarfs did you say there are? You made a noise, but that noise wasn't a number". That is to say, they'd be like Trenin but more so, they'd refuse to accept any hypotheticals about infinite objects/operations even if they're countable.

Comment: Anyway, this answer is a bit like solving a puzzle "I have one ball and a knife. I need two balls. How do I get them?" by appealing to the Banach-Tarski dissection. Perfectly reasonable as long as the puzzle is about surprising consequences of the axiom of choice, not about actual balls cut up with actual knives. The answer makes a point, but the point is not about what dwarfs in hats can do, it's about uncountable infinities.

Comment: @dmg You started this by saying you can recognize PI.  My point is there are an uncountable number of sequences here and it is not as simple as recognizing a few irrational number sequences.  The majority of the real numbers are transcendental, which means that you can't even express them with algebraic numbers in an equation.

Comment: A solution should show how the class is recognized.  To wave your hands and say it is unimportant how this is done because there is no point in arguing about infinities is a bit of a cop out.

Comment: All I would like to know is what theoretical algorithm or method do the dwarves use to recognize the class?  I am not arguing about the physical impossibility of the question, only the theoretical solution to the theoretical question.

Comment: I don't understand what "Choice of a representative can be easily defined as choosing the sequence where the differences appear at the beginning of the sequence and are lexicographically smaller." means. The differences to what? Lexicographically smaller than what?

Comment: The representative is not well defined in your solution. The "difference" is not a property of a single sequence, but a pair of sequences. For any given sequence we can choose another one for which the different part end at an arbitrarily large position, so there's no string for which the difference appear "at the beginning" only. And the class doesn't have the smallest element lexically (except for `(0)` class), as for any given element you can construct a smaller sequence by changing first `1` to `0`. The rest of solution is great, but we need a solid representative choice algorithm.

Comment: @SteveJessop I laughed out loud when I read *"Using the axiom of choice the prisoners pick a representative from each equivalence class."* in the other answer. Now I'm imagining a meeting of the Dwarven bureaucracy where they're officially picking representatives from each equivalence class "using the axiom of choice". Maybe in a Greg Egan short story that would work.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the following [link](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/A-dwarf-killing-giant-lines-up-10-dwarfs-from-shortest-to-tallest-Each-dwarf-can-see-all-the-shortest-dwarfs-in-front-of-h-QTN_491010.htm). The one answer which is simple to understand is the High pitch and low pitch. Each dwarfs answers his hat color in either high pitch or low pitch depending on the next dwarfs hat whether its in Red or Blue color.

Comment: Well that's certainly got the merit of simplicity!

Comment: The linked question is explicitly about the finite case; and your answer, while clever, isn't really satisfying: the intent is clearly that each dwarf can communicate only one bit to the neighbor in front of him.

Comment: They could impart several bits, if required: high/low, loud/quiet, fast/slow - and remember that humans (and presumably dwarves) are not binary - we can at the very least differentiate three (high/normal/low, fast/normal/slow, loud/normal/quiet) levels for each of these measurements. I make that a minimum of 27 bits even assuming that three levels per measurement is as as fine grained as we can get, that there is only one word and there are no other ways to inflect the word.

Comment: No, this is wrong. The dwarves can only call out a hat color, they can't do it in different pitches.

Comment: Says who? I don't see that in the rules

Comment: I had rewritten the rules, check the edit. Now the riddle should be clear.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that saves all the dwarves except (maybe) the first one. It is very similar to the one given by theosza, but it also mixes an idea used in the original problem with finitely  many dwarves.

We partition $\{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ with the equivalence $ (x_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \sim (y_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ if and only if there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that forall $ n \geq k $ we have that $x_n=y_n$. Now with the axiom of choice, the dwarves choose a representative $\tilde{x} =(\tilde{x}_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ from each equivalence class. Now the first dwarf sees in front of him a sequence of $ (x_j)_{j \geq 1} $ and he knows the class of equivalence and hence the representative $\tilde{x}$, so he can determine a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq k$ we have $x_n = \tilde{x}_n$. Now the representative and the real sequence of hats may differ only on finitely many hats, the first $k$ hats, the first dwarf sees $k-1$ hats and says "blue" if $x_n \neq \tilde{x}_n $ for an odd number of indices $1 \leq n \leq k-1$ and says "red" if $x_n \neq \tilde{x}_n $ for an even number of indices $1  \leq n \leq k-1 $. The second dwarf sees $(x_j)_{j \geq 2}$, he knows $\tilde{x}$ and he knows also if the representative and the sequences of hats differ from an even number or an odd number of hats (because he hears what the first dwarf said), so he can deduce the color of his hat, i.e. he can deduce if either $x_1 = \tilde{x}_1$ or $x_1 \neq \tilde{x}_1$. The third one knows $\tilde{x}$, he sees $(x_j)_{j \geq 3} $, he knows also $x_1$ and he can deduce $x_2$ thanks to the first dwarf. Inductively we continue in this way, the $n$-th dwarf sees $(x_j)_{j \geq n}$, he knows the representative $\tilde{x}$, he knows $(x_j)_{1 \leq j \leq n-2}$, and thanks to the first dwarf he can deduce his hat, i.e. if $x_{n-1}$ is equal to $\tilde{x}_{n-1}$ or differs from $\tilde{x}_{n-1}$.  So all the dwarves, except maybe the first one, guess correctly because they all follow the same representative $\tilde{x} $.

Answer (score -1):

I was wondering if a dwarf with infinite range of sight can identify repeating pattern(s)?

<strike>What if there is only one single pattern that is infinite? This would mean the dwarfs can't be saved :(</strike>

Due to the fact that the number of dwarfs is infinite, there must be a repeating pattern at some point (this is almost too complicated for me now!). With infinite sight, every dwarf can find his own position within the repeating pattern (which can be very, very, very long).

Having said that, a dwarf can never be sure whether he really identified a pattern correctly since the number of dwarfs is infinite and he would have to see *all dwarfs at once* in order to be sure - which is impossible due to "*infinite number*",... I think?

Comment: There can be an infinite sequence which does not have a repeating pattern. For example `rbrrbbrrrbbb...`

Comment: @dmg (read the <strike>'deleted'</strike> line). You are right, but it is *infinite* and 'infinite' includes the guarantee of a repeating pattern somewhere. I think this is a matter of definition?

Comment: PI is an example of a non-repeating infinite pattern.

Comment: But you never know because you can never see ALL decimals (infinite, you know) - maybe there is some pattern in the infinite distance... it is a conflict between definition and brain and I think we will never agree because we simply *can't*!

Comment: The brain doesn't really handle infinity well :) Just look at [Cantor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor)

Comment: @bobbee What do you mean by "pattern"? Do you mean a sequence of hat colors that repeats forever, starting from some point? If so, it can be shown that almost no sequences have a pattern.

Comment: I think of pattern as a sequence of hat colors that repeats forever, yes. Therefore I don't think this will work :(

Comment: OK: Better example than PI:
what about 0,1 01 001 0001 00001 000001 ... ? 
Is there a pattern, that repeats itself ?

Comment: As I said, you never know unless you oversee an infinite number and we can never find an answer to it.

Comment: @bobbee: well, if you can never know, you certainly can't rely on there being one as in your answer. Mathematicians have various techniques for defining this sort of thing, but with respect, trying to deal with it without seeing or re-inventing those techniques is a bit like a monkey trying to play chess. Even in the unlikely event that it moves the pieces according to the rules, it won't play well because it doesn't understand the goal. There are much better puzzles for the purpose of *introducing* infinity, for example see "Hilbert's Hotel".

Comment: There is an endless-monkey theory :)

Comment: @bobbee: ah, yes, watching the best monkey out of an infinite number of monkeys play chess is awesome. I was referring to watching one monkey play chess ;-)

Comment: All of the irrational numbers named in comments so far have patterns, simply because it's impossible to indicate precisely a number that doesn't.  I recommend considering the case where every single dwarf's hat color is chosen randomly, rather than following the bits of a number chosen in advance.  The bits will still correspond to an irrational number, but it will be a properly patternless one.

Comment: @Brilliand Sure, every number indicated so far has a pattern in that sense. However, he is speaking a pattern specifically as "a sequence of hat colors that repeats forever". In this sense, *any* irrational number is a counter-example.